# Run BIRT report engine

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, birt

I'm nobe about BIRT and Jasper soft report engines. As I understand BIRT is belongings to eclipse company and Jasper soft is belongs to  JasperReports Lib LGPLV3 JasperSoft Studio EPL.
I want to run BIRT or Jasper soft without any IDE(as Jasper report engine ). Is it possible?  If is possible for which one?

Comment: `JasperReports` - Yes, it is possible

Comment: How about BIRT and Jasper soft?

Comment: Www.jaspersoft.com

Comment: I want to run BIRT or Jasper soft without any IDE(as Jasper report engine ).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my main question is about "birt",can I run it as Jasper without eclipse IDE?

Comment: Could you please edit the question - to be clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want (your question is a bit unclear) - yes, it is possible with BIRT and with JasperReports.

For JasperReports, you'll need the JasperReports Server (or whatever it's called). You deploy your reports modules to that server. Then you can run a report either by using the server's browser-based self-service UI or you can run them from within your program by calling a URL/WebService.

For Eclipse BIRT, it's similar. The download you're looking for is the BIRT Runtime Engine. This is basically just a bunch of JAR files (note: it comes in two flavours: OSGI based and just JARs). As an example, the runtime engine contains a BIRT servlet. This allows you to run any report by calling a URL. The second option is to integrate the runtime engine directly into your Java application. Search for "integrating BIRT" and "RunAndRenderTask" or "RunTask" and "RenderTask", you'll probably find examples.